# My First PCB - EMI Problem on Poorly Earth Grounded Test Place

Tags: pcb, stm32, analog, noise, emi-filtering

A PCB design amateur here. Stumbled upon a hard problem right at my first PCB design. I have tried to comply with the layout rules of thumb for SI and EMC, but still encountered with strong EMI problems with the produced card. Need suggestions to remedy the interference problem. I also appreciate your suggestions for general design improvements.

The main function of the PCB is to cyclically read the Q4 phototransistor analog output, which is irregular according to the transparency of the material, and activate relay coil over connector when it is above a certain threshold level. The side functions are RS485, NFC communications. The circuit functions normal when there is no noise source, but when a 0.25 kW industrial AC drive mounted on the chassis is activated by firing up the IGBT PWM, holding the motor even at 0 speed, the 8-bit analog signal fluctuates to extremes (0 to 255), where 0 corresponds to 0V, 255 to 3.3V and the minimum analog total sampling period is 16us at 8-bits. The noise coupled to the PCB is at multiples of 3kHz. In 1 second the SWD debug interface locks. In the STM32CubeMonitor diagram the blue curve is real time analog value with no filtering. The green, yellow and red curves should be constant. But when they start to fluctuate, SWD locks. The microcontroller is STM32F030C8T6. I use STM32CubeIDE for debugging. Power supply is Meanwell RS-25-5 SMPS. The Earth Ground of the testing place is very weak, but still I want to have a design that is robust. My Rigol DS1104 oscilloscope probes picks up noise from air, so I could not use them properly in this case.

I have tried lots of things but couldn't get around this problem. Some of things I tried are:

- Thought that top and bottom layer ground pour via stitching is weak, so I soldered short jumper wires directly from the power connector GND (0 V) to seemingly weak GND nodes.
- I have used shielded power supply cables to the PCB.
- Thought that maybe +3.3 V supply trace forms loop around PCB. So I cut it through after phototransistor with no improvement.
- Used capacitor multiplier for power supply with no luck.
- After adding Opamp voltage follower to the phototransistor output, only small improvement was seen on the analog voltage quality.
- Adding bulk capacitors (multiple 1000 uF) on the 5 V supply rails.
- Disabled RS-485 and NFC.
- Grounded the outermost loop (Earth GND) with SMPS 0V

Below are the schematic, layout and measurement diagram. Thank you.

Schematic:

[image: Schematic]

Top Layer:

[image: Top Layer]

Bottom Layer:

[image: Bottom Layer]

Top and Bottom Layers Together:

[image: Top and Bottom Layers]

Measurement Diagram:

[image: Measurement Diagram]

Comment: Part numbers seem out of sync -- R9 on the schematic is R8 on the PCB .

Comment: And the layout around the optocoupler is unfortunate. You should rotate it so that it straddles the gap in the ground planes and make sure all traces and components are on the correct side of the gap (eg R7/R8). Not saying this is the cause of the problem though.

Comment: Hello Damien, thank you I will update the schematic picture hopefully in a short time.

Comment: Also, you can make the page size bigger on kicad by selecting a larger paper size.

Comment: Is there a reason why RS-485 bus ground is not connected to RS-485 transceiver ground?

Comment: Hello @Justme, I guess I have connected RS485+/- correctly. Considered cable shield as a third connection to chassis, not to the circuit 0V ground.

Comment: @SemihBoyno But RS-485 needs stable ground reference between devices. The grounds of RS-485 chips must be connected together. If you have only shield and no common ground wire between devices, you must use the shield as ground reference between devices. Especially because the Meanwell supply appears to have floating, non-earth referenced output. Also which chip that is, SP3485 or MAX485? SP3485 is not intended to be run at 5V.

Comment: This is a good layout... if it were a 4-layer layout. For 2 layers, you only want tiny jumpers on the ground plane, like little holes in Swiss cheese. No long traces or anything like that unless they are on the edge of the board, and they are "quiet" traces of course.

Comment: @Justme, sorry, silly me. The actual chip is Gatemode GM3085E on the PCB since it was readily available. I will improve and update PCB on RS-485 common ground reference, thank you.

Comment: Are you very cost constrained with high volume production? If not, consider a four layer PCB if the suggestions below aren’t enough. Go for a _solid_ ground plane.

Comment: @winny, I will consider 4-layer board. Which stackup would be the best: gnd-pwr/signal-signal-ground or pwr/signal-gnd-gnd-signal ?

Comment: That question is often debated here. For prototyping, I use signal+ground pour/solid GND/solid Vcc/signal+ground pour. This is to have access to probing and if needed cut and jump on the outer layers. Avoid all long traces if you can and feel free to use 0 ohm jumpers to get a signal underneath another over routing it on GND plane. Please also understand that your options for routing is very much determined by your floor planning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The input to the ADC is very high impedance and so it's relatively easy to inject noise into it.  Look at the return path for the ADC trace, it's completely carved up by other traces, etc.  There is literally no direct path.  The green path is perhaps best, there may be a route via the purple path, not sure.

[image: return paths]

The way to fix is to provide a good return path.  Scratch away L1 solder resist near Q2 and solder on some fine wire to GND.  Run the wire dead on top of the ADC trace as far as the stm32.  Then at the chip run the wire as tight as you can to the package and land it either on pin 8 (vssa) or the gnd pin of the cap connected to pin 8.

[image: Wire extra return path]

This may or may not be enough.  Your signal is going to carry any noise that the 3v3 rail has via R24/R26.  Suggest you also add ceramic 100nF cap locally on the board from the top of R24 to the top of R26.  This might help shunt any high frequency noise across the transistor and keep it out of your signal.

None of this will fix the real problem that many traces don't have sensible return paths and so are both aggressors producing noise whenever they switch and victims recieving noise from any signal trying to traverse the gnd plane.

You really need to add 2 more layers and use them for solid GND.

You may be able to improve matters by using some strategically added gnd straps soldered across sections of the GND plane copper.  The more you scratch away resist and solder on bits of copper braid that bridges from one GND land to another, the better the return paths, the less your design will be susceptible to noise.  Looking at L2 if you can solder across the traces that radiate under the MCU and the long trace headed towards the motor driver you may very well go a long way towards reducing the problem.

Others have pointed out that the big circular traces that run around the board edge are possibly coupling to the fields produced by your motor ... You may be producing severe voltage fluctuations on 3v3 and this may be disturbing the MCU and its analog performance will be terrible if this is happening.  A shielded power cable is only any use if the shield isn't conducting your power.  You don't describe the nature of your shielded cable so hard to be sure about that.

If you can disconnect all cables that aren't critical to testing (buttons, LEDs, etc) that might help.  Any one of these could be injecting noise.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your comprehensive answer. I will probably go with 4-layer board. Which stackup would be the best: gnd-pwr/signal-signal-ground or pwr/signal-gnd-gnd-signal?

Comment: Should I continue to use 3.3V LDO or design a switching converter for best EMI performance?

Comment: Sig gnd gnd sig.   You can route 3v3 on L4 point to point,.make sure you have a decoupling cap wherever it is needed.

Comment: Well that depends on the PSRR of your regulator.   The proximity of 24v power and GND to the other power and GND in your power cables is always going to couple some of the motor noise onto the other supply voltages.  If you can split them up, I would.  Are you feeding 3.3 out of this board to something else?  If so, consider whether that's really necessary.  If it is I would be very tempted to use a LDO to feed the 3.3 out and a second LDO to feed MCU.  You should edit your question to describe the signal you are trying to measure (amplitude, frequency range, required resolution)

Comment: And finally don't forget to add gnd stitch via next to any via or group of vias...wherever a signal crosses from L1 to L4 you also need to facilitate the return path to cross from L2 to L3.  The L1 signal is referenced to L2 GND but the L4 signal is referenced to L3 GND. The GND via lets this work.

Answer (score 0):

Does noise appear between your GND and your chassis earth? (which is what I presume the earth symbol means that only connects to J7 pin 2) It is not connected to GND and it runs right round the board. It may be acting as a loop antenna round your board. If it is acting as a loop antenna and that is causing a/the problem then putting a break in it might not solve the problem as it would turn it into a form of folded dipole. If it were connected to GND would that make a difference?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello @tirnasjimmy, noise is produced by AC motor drive and introduced to chassis strongly by the AC motor. I isolated the PCB from chassis. The outermost loop is the Earth GND. I have grounded it to SMPS 0V with no improvement. Still there is very strong EMI pickup. But I haven't tried to break this Earth GND loop.